# Is it possible to query Quip spreadsheet fields directly with the API or must the html be parsed?

Tags: api, json, fields, quip

I am attempting to extract a date from a quip spreadsheet cell in a Node.js application. I am able to extract the html from the html property of the object returned by the getThread API call, but it is much more complicated to parse the html than it would be to simply query the API for a spreadsheet row based on the an field and work with JSON.

Comment: are you able to utilize the [section ID](https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation) within the html? `Quip documents are broken down into smaller units we call sections. Every paragraph in a document is a separate section, as is every item in a list or cell in a table. The Quip Automation API outputs documents as HTML for convenience, and the elements in the HTML have id attributes specifying their internal section ID`. Do you have an example of what your return looks like?

Comment: Thanks Kris. I ended up using cheerio to parse the html using the id attributes of the cells I wanted. I think my question is answered and it would be more of a feature request at this point for a mechanism to query cells directly by row/column.